# Использование ; в формулах openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Необходимо использовать формулы которые будут работать в excel. Пишу в программе

```
all_ws.cell(row=1, column=15).value='=ЕСЛИ(H2>1000;1;0)'
```

но программа по какой-то причине все ; заменяет на | и естественно формула после этого отказывается работать.
Вот что я вижу в ячейке после этого

```
=если(H2>1000|1|0)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В самом начале руководства "Для использования в ячейке встроенной формулы/функции электронной таблицы совместно с модулем openpyxl необходимо использовать английское имя этой формулы/функции, а аргументы формулы должны быть разделены запятыми, а не другими пунктуационными знаками, такими как точка с запятой." https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-openpyxl/vstroennye-excel-formuly/